# Motion planning for non-serial chain robotic arms

Tags: moveit, robotic-arm, inverse-kinematics, motion-planning, ros-noetic

I am trying to do position motion planning with inverse kinematics for the [MeArm](https://grabcad.com/library/mearm-v1-0-robot-arm-1) model.
I followed MoveIt tutorials and was able to achieve what I wanted with their provided robot example. However, I found out that the solvers MoveIt uses only support serial chains [(here)](http://docs.ros.org/en/kinetic/api/moveit_tutorials/html/doc/kinematics_configuration/kinematics_configuration_tutorial.html).
Is there any alternative method for doing motion planning/IK that supports non-serial chain robotic arms ?

Answer (score 1):

You can try and use this:

https://github.com/RobeeContech/hardware_interface_wrappers

This is a repo we created for managing a unique transmission of our SCARA robot.

**This is not maintained** but it works fine as far as our tests go and we made it public if someone wants to use it.

you can look at those for references:
https://github.com/RobeeContech/transmission_manager
https://github.com/RobeeContech/robee_transmissions

this opens an abstract class to wrap your hardware interface and thus you can work with a normal serial ik solver

This means that there is quite a lot to write on your own and calculate your transmissions accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Running a search in google, return this repo, which, apparently can tackle your issue.

https://github.com/davetcoleman/moveit_whole_body_ik

On the other hand, it seems that none of the "officially" supported kinematic plugins can handle non-serial chains so probably you'll need to build something customized

Answer (score 0):

Moveit implements by default a kdl based inverse kinematics implemened with its kinematic plugins. This works "ok" for serial robots. For complex robots like yours the intended approach ia to develop your own kinematic plugin.